# Proper method of importing functions

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

After some very helpful tips learning about javascript promises and how they behave, I am looking for some help with properly importing/exporting functions from one javascript file into another which is run via NodeJS.

Essentially I want basicNode.js to open an html doc, and then once that is open (and the promise implied via the open(html) statement is 100% complete/finalized) run the function from change.js to alter the html to show "Hello" in the place of "Welcome to JavaScript". This will provide proof of concept that can then be extrapolated for a project dealing with automating reports at my internship, so any help is greatly appreciated

basic.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>  
</head>  
<body>
<p>Date/Time: <span id="datetime"></span></p>
  
<p id="here">Welcome to JavaScript</p>  
<form>  
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="changeThis()"/>  
</form>  
</body> 
<script>
var dt = new Date();
    document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="change.js"></script> 
<!--
<script>waitForElementToDisplay("#here",function(){alert("Hi");},1000,9000);</script> 
--> 
</html>
```

change.js

```
function changeThis() {
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = "Hello";
}

module.exports={changeThis};
```

basicNode.js

```
const open = require('open');
var { change }  = require('./change')
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
global.document = new JSDOM('./basic.html').window.document;

const main = async () => {
  await open('./basic.html');
  change.changeThis();
}

main();
```

EDIT:after some tinkering, this is how I accomplished my task: in change.js, I set up the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const html = fs.readFileSync('./basic.html');
const dom = new JSDOM(html);

function changeThis() {
console.log("called changeThis() function, should alter the html")
var x = dom.window.document.getElementById('here').textContent;
console.log(x);
dom.window.document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = 'Hello'
var x = dom.window.document.getElementById('here').textContent;
console.log(x);
}

module.exports.changeThis = changeThis
```

Then, to call/import this function in my basicNode.js file:

```
var change = require('./change');

change.changeThis();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `change.js`-file you are exporting your function as a named export. A named export is normally used if you are only exporting one function from a file (this is not a rule), and named exports are mainly used when you are exporting several functions from a file.

This is a named export

```
module.exports= { changeThis };
```

A named export is imported as

```
var { changeThis }  = require('./change')
```

The opposite to a named export is a default export.

```
module.exports = changeThis
```

This is imported as

```
var changeThis = require("./change")
```

---

Edit:
If what you want is to read the file, moodify the DOM and then write it to a file again, then you can do it like this.

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

// Read the file from the system
const fs = require('fs');
const html = fs.readFileSync('./basic.html');

// Create a jsdom and modify the file
const dom = new JSDOM(html);
dom.window.document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = 'Hello';

// write the file to disc
fs.writeFileSync(
    './basicUpdated.html',
    dom.window.document.documentElement.outerHTML
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation @christianeide, so to clarify: If I went with the first example of import/export, would I then in the code execute the function by writing
`changeThis()` or maybe `changeThis.changeThis()`
sorry if this seems obvious, I've only been using NodeJS for like 2 weeks so adapting my basic javascript knowledge to fit isn't super fine tuned

Comment: No worries :) Ether way you call the function simply by `changeThis()`

Comment: sweet, looks like it's calling the function correctly now. However, I think probably circling back to the promise issue I had before, I'm now getting a can't set properties of null from the call to change the html

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you are attempting to do. Your example is doing two things, both creating a virualt DOM and trying to modify if (Jsdom), and at the same time open up a page with the open package. 

If what you want is to read a page, modify its content and then write it to a file again, see my updated answer for an example of that.

Comment: I think your updated example will do what I'm looking for, however I need it to be able to do it via calling a function from change.js file in the basicNode.js file. So essentially put the dom.window... line from your example into a function in the change.js file and then execute that function in basicNode.js, 

I've tried examples for importing/exporting functions&variables from w3schools, sitepoint and some other places but I either get changeThis() is not a function or cannot read properties of undefined.

Comment: Okay. That will make things more complicated. What can we edit? Do you have any control over the basicNode.js-file? Or why do you need to separate the logic into two files? Do you need to use the basicNode.js-file at all?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, formatted as module.exports.changeThis = changeThis; and then for importing as var change = require('./change'); and call the function as change.changeThis();

Comment: I needed to have the two separate files as a proof of concept that nodeJS could execute a function that edits/gets info from an html from another js file without needing to execute all the functions in that file.